# How to authorize shopify webhook on backend application?

Tags: asp.net, shopify

I use a dotnet application on the backend to manage inventories and the Shopify store to manage orders.

Calling a Shopify REST endpoint from a third-party application forces us to do authorization but when Shopify calls my application endpoint how can I authorize and verify them?

```
[Authenticate]
some endpoint () {
    // this endpoint is exposed for the Shopify webhook.
}
```

This is the response return when creating a webhook on Shopify.

[image: 1]

Now when this webhook will trigger it will hit my endpoint and without authorization, it will fail.

How can I authorize this webhook?

Answer (score 0):

Shopify apps do HMAC validation to ensure that the request received by them has actually originated from the Shopify platform. Shopify uses a secret key to generate an HMAC of the request body and sends it along with the request.